# pywin32 CreateEvent and Apache

Tags: python, django, apache, winapi

I have a website in Django1.1.1 deployed in Apache2.0. In the backend I have a launcher script that starts three python processes that interact with the frontend. One of these processes uses a Windows Event (using CreateEvent) that communicates with Apache.

My problem is that when I run the launcher script first and then start Apache everything seems to be working fine, but when I start Apache first and then run launcher the process with the Windows event is never launched. On starting the process on command line it dies with the error
`pywintypes.error: (5, 'CreateEvent', 'Access is denied.')`

I think this is a permission issue where Apache is running as SYSTEM user and the launcher running as me. Any ideas how I can fix this? 
It could be something else too, any ideas?
I am a noob on Windows so please bear with me. BTW I am using Windows XP and python 2.4
Thanks
S

UPDATE: 
I eventually used python recipe [Controlling Windows Services](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/115875-controlling-windows-services/) to always launch Apache service post my script. My problem is resolved!

Answer (score 0):

Are you specifying a [security descriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379563(v=VS.85).aspx) in the call to [CreateEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682396(VS.85).aspx) (through the lpEventAttributes argument)?

See the section 5 (Synchronization Object Security and Access Rights) on the following page for details:

- [Processes and Threads: Synchronization](http://www.tenouk.com/ModuleV2.html)

Comment: Thanks for this link. I used a different solution that I have updated above.